# Is there a way to log out a specific user using firebase auth go sdk?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication

## background of this question

I'm using firebase auth for user authentication on my app.
I realized that firebase doesn't have a log of user information changes, so I can't answer user questions about it.
So, I'm planning to move the feature of changing user account info (like email, display name, and password) from using the client-side firebase auth library to using server-side firebase auth SDK for the purpose of taking logs of these changes to use for user support. Also, I'd like to make logout a user who changes account info.

I've looked for the appropriate API on the document [firebase.google.com/go/v4/auth](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4/auth#UserInfo) and found [UpdateUser](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4/auth#Client.UpdateUser) function. The struct **UserToUpdate** which is a parameter of UpdateUser can set a new email address, new password and new display name, but I can't find to set the parameter to make a **user logout**.

## my question

Is there a way to log out a specific user by firebase auth go SDK?

Comment: Why don't you logout on client side after your server returns successful response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication's client-side sign-in is based on ID tokens, which are valid until their built-in expiration (by default: an hour after they are minted). Since no server keeps a list of all the ID tokens it has minted, there is no way to mark a token as invalid on such a list either.

The common approach to revoke access for a user is to:

1. [Revoke the **refresh** token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens), so that they can no longer mint new ID tokens with it.
2. Add the ID token(s) of the user to a self-managed list of revoked ID tokens.
3. [Detect the presence of an ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation) in this list from your server-side code and security rules.
4. Optionally [detect the refresh token revocation on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#respond_to_token_revocation_on_the_client)

Instead of logging the user out, you can also [force-refresh their ID token/profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload) on the client to get the latest information from the server.